# Set font to bold in one cell, when row is selected. Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

How can I set the font-weight to bold in one specific cell when I select a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setCell` inside of `onSelectRow` to change the style of the cell. For example

```js
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (id !== lastSel && typeof lastSel !== 'undefined') {
        $this.jqGrid('setCell', lastSel, 'total', '', {'font-weight': 'normal'});
    }
    $this.jqGrid('setCell', id, 'total', '', {'font-weight': 'bold'});
    lastSel = id;
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MakeCellBoldOnRowSelection.htm). In the way you can set any other CSS styles.